# How to print attributes of related objects in zope templates?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I wrote an dexterity type with a field relating to another object:

```python
institution = RelationChoice(
    title=_(u"Institution"),
    source=ObjPathSourceBinder(
        object_provides=IInstitution.__identifier__
    ),
)
```

And also in the template I wrote:

```xml
<span id="institution" tal:content="context/institution" />
```

But it prints:

```
<z3c.relationfield.relation.RelationValue object at 0xe3a032c>
```

I have tried to get attributes to build a link to the item, but the next doesn't works:

```xml
<span id="institution" tal:content="context/institution/absolute_url" />
```

How can I get the attributes of the objecto to make a link to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference objects are documented [in the Dexterity developer manual](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/references). You are looking for the `to_object` attribute:

```xml
<span id="institution" tal:content="context/institution/to_object/absolute_url" />
```

which would insert the URL of the linked object, or you could show the `Title` instead:

```xml
<span id="institution" tal:content="context/institution/to_object/Title" />
```